# Which Batman story is this scene from?

Tags: story-identification, dc, batman, episode-identification, lee-bermejo

This artwork is from artist and comic book illustrator [Lee Bermejo](https://www.instagram.com/leebermejoart/?hl=en). I have read some stories by him, like *Batman: Noël*, the crossover *Batman/Deathblow: After the Fire* and a story about Lex Luthor in which Batman made a brief appearance.

I understand that that is not all of Lee Bermejo's work for DC or related to Batman, and I understand that, as in the Lex Luthor story, this artwork can come from a story from a different hero or team.

It does seem to be a page from a story, as apposed to some random art, sketch or cover, although there are no dialogs.

Does anybody know from which story this page comes from?

[image: A panel from a Batman comic]
<sup>*Click on the image above for a full size version*</sup>

Just in case, a brief description: the page illustrates some street fight between gang members. We see Batman gauntlet strap some harness on his utility belt, and then Batman fall on the back of one of the gang members. Batman armor has the unmistakable Lee Bermejo style.

Answer (score 9):

A reverse google image search suggests *Batman Black & White* issue 3, and the artist, Lee Bermejo's page confirms it [here](http://leebermejo.blogspot.com/2013/11/batman-black-white-3.html).